# This is edit form one of the component from my project. There are no errors and also no warnings

Tags: react-hooks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import {FormGroup, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, Typography, styled, Button} from '@mui/material'
import  { editUser }  from '../services/editUser.js'
import  { getUser }  from '../services/getUser.js'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const Container = styled(FormGroup)`
  width : 50%;
  margin : 5% auto 0 auto; 
`

const FormCont = styled(FormControl)`
  margin-top : 20px
`

const defaultValues={
  name : "",
  username : "",
  email : "",
  phone : ""
}



export default function AddUser() {

  const { id } = useParams()

  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  const [User, setUser] = useState(defaultValues)

  // My problem might be here in the function bellow
  const onChangeInput = (e)=>{
    setUser({...User , [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
  }

  const editUsers = async ()=>{
    await editUser(User)
    navigate('/alluser')
  }



  useEffect(() => {
    loadUserDetails()
  })
  
  const loadUserDetails = async () => {
    const res = await getUser(id)
    setUser(res.data)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Typography variant="h4">Edit User</Typography>
        <FormCont>
          <InputLabel>Name</InputLabel>
          <Input onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput(e)} name="name" value={User.name}/>
        </FormCont>
        <FormCont>
          <InputLabel>Username</InputLabel>
          <Input onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput(e)} name='username' defaultValue={User.username}/>
        </FormCont>
        <FormCont>
          <InputLabel>Email</InputLabel>
          <Input onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput(e)} name='email' defaultValue={User.email}/>
        </FormCont>
        <FormCont>
          <InputLabel>Phone</InputLabel>
          <Input onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput(e)} name='phone' defaultValue={User.phone}/>
        </FormCont>
        <FormCont>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={editUsers} >Edit User</Button>
        </FormCont>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have created a edit form in which i have fetched data using my own API. I have declared values of input fields from that API data. My issue is that my users are not getting updated in useState's setUser() function() that I used to update my users. My expectation were really very simple that the form must contain the values as the component gets mounted and after that user can edit the values that he/she wants to edit.